# Which distro for this ancient laptop?

Tags: distributions, laptop

I have ancient laptop and need a distro for it which will do basic stuff  mainly Word processing, Web Browsing, Playing some songs and movies on it.

The specs are:

> Intel Celeron M 440 @ 1.60 Ghz
>   1GB Ram
>   Intel 945GMA
>   20 GB HDD

Is there any distro which will work fluently? I have tried Lubuntu/Ubuntu/Mint/Crunchbang/PC Linux OS and must say either I don't like environment which comes with it or something doesn't work. I prefer to use KDE if it's possible on this hardware. Will Manjaro or Open SuSE work good on my laptop? Any other distros which could be recommended?

P.S Puppy Linux and Damn Small Linux don't come into the game.

Comment: Fedora has a KDE version, you could try that.  Make sure you install some swap, because with 1 GB RAM you'll be pushing things a bit.  But it will work.

Comment: Ah, kids. 1.6Ghz and 1GBof RAM is not ancient. You can pretty much use any distro as long as you don't bloat it with huge desktop managers and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, take a look at the minimum required specs of some distros:

- [Fedora 20](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/20/html/Release_Notes/sect-Release_Notes-Welcome_to_Fedora_.html):

  - 1GHz or faster processor
  - 1GB System Memory
  - 10GB unallocated drive space
- [OpenBSD](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq3.html#SelectHW):

  - Processor: 100MHz Pentium or better processor.
  - 64M RAM or better: If you wish to run X, 128M would be a better starting point.
  - Hard disk: A 1G hard disk.
- [Debian](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch03s04.html.en):

  - A Pentium 4, 1GHz system is the minimum recommended for a desktop system.
  - 256 MB
  - 5GB hard disk

I still have an operative Debian system running in a IBM ThinkPad 390X with a Pentium III Coppermine (450MHz) and (upgraded) to 128MB RAM.

So you can install any distribution in a PC with the specs you refer. If you need a desktop, choose a lightweight one (from LXDE to ratpoison, the choices are many), and get yourself used to CLI applications (`mutt` instead of Thunderbird, `elinks` instead o Firefox, ...). KDE needs more resources than what you have there, is not a good choice.

Comment: Also XFCE is quite light and complete. As for the "mutt instead of Thunderbird" remark, you can just use a web-based client and have comfortable interface.